# Sed in place replacement on Mac

Tags: macos, bash, sed

This is a question regards to *sed* on **Mac**, which requires a zero-length string for in-place replacement without backup files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -x

SEDOPT='-i "" '
echo $SEDOPT
sed $SEDOPT -e "s/a/a/g" filename.txt
sed "$SEDOPT" -e "s/a/a/g" filename.txt
sed -i "" -e "s/a/a/g" filename.txt
```

If you execute the above commands, you will get the output like

```
1|+ SEDOPT='-i "" '
2|+ echo -i '""'
3|-i ""
4|+ sed -i '""' -e s/a/a/g filename.txt
5|+ sed '-i "" ' -e s/a/a/g filename.txt
6|+ sed -i '' -e s/a/a/g filename.txt
```

I'm setting up a sed option variable `SEDOPT`, that will be changed depends distro.

Can someone help me on make the output of line 4 and 5 behave like line 6?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes do not nest the way you are expecting them to. Use an array to store arguments.

```
SEDOPT=( -i "" )
sed "${SEDOPT[@]}" -e "s/a/a/g" filename.txt
```

---

With the line

```
sed -i "" ...
```

the first two arguments to `sed` are `-i` and the empty string; `bash` removes the double quotes during the *quote removal* phase of its evaluation of the command line.

With the code

```
SEDOPT='-i ""'
sed $SEDOPT ...
```

the variable `SEDOPT` expands to a string containing a literal whitespace and two double quotation marks. The result is subject to word splitting (where the whitespace is removed, leaving two separate words `-i` and `""` in place of the original string `-i ""`), but *not* quote removal, so the literal string `""` is passed to `sed` as the second argument.

Comment: Thank you, this bugged me for two days. I was being an amateur not thinking to use array to pass arguments.